# How to upload multi image in swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, image-uploading

I have to send more than one image at a time.create the product model as

product.cs:

```
  [JsonProperty("Image")]
  public List<IFormFile> Image { get; set; }
```

now i am trying to add more than one image from swagger .i entered the image path but it is not read the image file. What should i enter here?
[image: input]

I expect like blow:
[image]

Comment: Click "Add item"???? Sometimes reading the UI buttons is the easiest way to reach your goal

Comment: Your annotation library (Swashbuckle?) generated an OpenAPI 2.0 definition which does not support multiple file uploads. Multi-upload is supported in OpenAPI 3.0. See if your annotation library can generate OpenAPI 3.0 definitions instead.

Comment: For `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`, it does not support multiple files currently, you could refer [Multiple IFormFile upload #1029](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1029)

Comment: Starting from version 6.1.4 of Swashbuckle you can do it... check this thread https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/193

Answer (score 0):

Thisi example works with .NET 6:

```
public class DataTypeExample
{
    public string str { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> testFiles { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<List<string>> Post([FromForm] DataTypeExample dataTypeEx)
{
    var fileSizes = new List<string>();
    fileSizes.Add("You sent the string: " + dataTypeEx.str);
    foreach(var f in dataTypeEx.testFiles)
    {
        fileSizes.Add(f.FileName + ": " + f.Length.ToString() + " bytes");
    }
    
    return fileSizes;
}
```

Results in the following:

[image]